# Changed text input disappears immediately after being changed JavaScript Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, forms, input, tampermonkey

Writing a script to automate an action on a website. Tribalwars scavenging in case you are familiar with it. Using tampermonkey. Full code [in here](https://sharetext.me/ne66zijl). Line 164.
This is the input element I'm trying to change so I can submit the form afterwards. It does change but the new value flashes and disappears right away.

```
<input name="spear" type="text" value="" maxlength="5" max="99999" class="unitsInput input-nicer">
```

Using .value to change the input text:

```
unitsInput[i].value=spearman[currentScavenge];
```

Next step would be to click this button but the values are gone by then.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default free_send_button">Start</a>
```

How do I make it so the values stay changed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Tribalwars scavenging". Could you share a link to the actual page and post the code as a [mcve] in the question itself? I won't click on an external sharing site that's probably full of malware. Thanks.